# Проблема с установкой нового пакета (composer)

Tags: yii2, composer

Я начинающий разработчик на Yii, и у меня возникла следующая проблема - я делаю логин на сайт через социальные сети facebook и instagramm.
Для facebook я установил расширение yiisoft/yii2-authclient - и оно работает нормально - но возникла необходимость в логине через instagram - я выбрал расширение brainsrage/yii2-authclient-instagram - которое не могу установить через composer.
Мой composer.json

```js
{
    "name": "yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced",
    "description": "Yii 2 Advanced Project Template",
    "keywords": ["yii2", "framework", "advanced", "project template"],
    "homepage": "http://www.yiiframework.com/",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "support": {
        "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
        "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
        "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
        "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
        "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {
        "php": "~7.1.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2": "~2.0.6",
        "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "~2.0.0 || ~2.1.0",
        "dektrium/yii2-user": "^0.9.14",
        "dektrium/yii2-rbac": "1.0.0-alpha@dev",
        "kartik-v/yii2-krajee-base": "~1.9",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-depdrop": "~1.0.4",
        "creocoder/yii2-flysystem": "dev-master",
        "2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget": "^1.0@dev",
        "2amigos/yii2-tinymce-widget": "~1.1",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker": "@dev",
        "justcoded/yii2-settings": "*",
        "2amigos/yii2-file-upload-widget": "~1.0",
        "kartik-v/yii2-widget-rating": "dev-master",
        "yiisoft/yii2-httpclient": "^2.0@dev",
        "tinymce/tinymce": "~4.5.0",
        "giannisdag/yii2-check-login-attempts": "dev-master",
        "stichoza/google-translate-php": "~2.0",
        "yiidoc/yii2-redactor": "2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-authclient": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "~2.0.0",
        "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "~2.0.0",
        "codeception/base": "^2.2.3",
        "codeception/verify": "~0.3.1"
    },
    "config": {
        "process-timeout": 1800,
        "fxp-asset": {
            "enabled": false
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://asset-packagist.org"
        }
    ]
}
```

Сообщение об ошибке при composer require brainsrage/yii2-authclient-instagram:

```js
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for brainsrage/yii2-authclient-instagram dev-master -> satisfiable by brainsrage/yii2-authclient-instagram[dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: yiisoft/yii2-authclient[2.0.x-dev, 2.1.8].
    - Can only install one of: yiisoft/yii2-authclient[2.0.x-dev, 2.1.8].
    - Can only install one of: yiisoft/yii2-authclient[2.0.x-dev, 2.1.8].
    - Conclusion: install yiisoft/yii2-authclient 2.0.x-dev
    - Installation request for yiisoft/yii2-authclient (locked at 2.1.8, required as *) -> satisfiable by yiisoft/yii2-authclient[2.1.8].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Заранее спасибо за рекомендации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer вам сообщает, что не может удовлетворить зависимости для устанавливаемого Вами нового пакета, т.к. требование к версии пакета *yiisoft/yii2-authclient*, конфиликтует с требованиями пакетов уже установленных.

Посмотреть информацию о пакете *brainsrage/yii2-authclient-instagram*:

`composer show -a -- brainsrage/yii2-authclient-instagram`

Ему требуется версия пакета *yiisoft/yii2-authclient* *>=2.0.4* и *<2.1.0*

Посмотреть информацию о пакетах, также зависящие от *yiisoft/yii2-authclient*:

```
composer depends yiisoft/yii2-authclient
```

Вывод у вас будет такой:

```
dektrium/yii2-user         dev-master  requires  yiisoft/yii2-authclient (^2.1.0)  
yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced  -           requires  yiisoft/yii2-authclient (2.1.*)
```

Из этого вывода видно, что два ранее установленых пакета имеют ту же зависимость от *yiisoft/yii2-authclient*. Они предъявляют требования к версии, которые composer удовлетворил - установил пакет *yiisoft/yii2-authclient* с версией *2.1.8*.

---

Моя рекомендация - выбрать другой пакет.